# JSON (simple) parsing of file returns null values

Tags: java, json

It's my first time working with a JSON file, so I went with simple JSON library. Here's what works:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class ParseCardJSON {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        Object obj;

        try {
          obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\owner\\Desktop\\A\\programming\\workspace\\MTG\\AllSets.json"));
          JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
          System.out.println(obj.toString());
          String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
          String color = (String) jsonObject.get("power");
          System.out.println("Name: " + name);
          System.out.println("color: " + color);

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So the `System.out.println(obj.toString());` prints out what I'm expecting:

```
({"LEA":{"name":"Limited Edition Alpha","code":"LEA","gathererCode":"1E","magicCardsInfoCode":"al","releaseDate":"1993-08-05","..)...
```

but the "name" and "color" `prinln`s are `null`. Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happen because the *name* property is not in the root.

In fact you have a *LEA* key that is in the root, and the value of that property is another Object, that contains the following keys : *name*, *code*, *gathererCode*, *magicCardsInfoCode*, etc...

So if you want extract the *name* property, you need to do something like this

```
JSONObject object = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("LEA");
String name = (String) object.get("name");
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: Appreciate it. So if I'm understanding, the entire JSON object is wrapped in a key, so I need to let my parser know that so that it delves beyond just the top level? Unfortuntely, jsonObject.get is throwing an error for me though (Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method get(Object) from the type HashMap). Any idea how to fix this? Removing the static in a main isn't really an option, right?

Comment: Could you provide the code please?
I'll show you the fix.

Comment: Looks like it's working now, so it must have been something little I was doing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. My pleasure